# Limitar quantidade de caracteres html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Fiz este *input* com html + css e está tudo ok, só não cosigo limitar o número de caracteres para 10, tentei o `maxlength="10"` mas não responde. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```html
<div class="searchBox">
    <input class="searchInput" type="number"  name="localizar" id="localizar" placeholder="numero do cliente">
    <button class="searchButton" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">
            search
        </i>
    </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: tentou usar o atributo `max` no seu `input`?  `maxlength` e geralmente usado para o `type="text"`. Se for um numero de celular, por exemplo, mude o `type` para `text` - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp

Comment: Muito obrigado! Matou de primeira! troquei o type por text ai o campo aceitou o maxlength.

Answer (score 2):

A propriedade `maxlength` não funciona se o tipo do `input` for `"number"`. Para esse problema, uma solução simples é mudar o tipo para `text`.

```html
<input class="searchInput" type="text" name="localizar" id="localizar" placeholder="numero do cliente" maxlength="10"/>
```

Mas se você precisa que o tipo seja número para melhor uso nos celulares, você pode utilizar o tipo `"tel"` que irá exibir um teclado numérico e o `maxlength` funcionará do mesmo jeito.

```html
<input class="searchInput" type="tel" name="localizar" id="localizar" placeholder="numero do cliente" maxlength="10"/>
```

Se por algum motivo você precisar utilizar o tipo `"number"`, a solução será com JavaScript, onde você deverá definir o evento `oninput` no HTML para executar uma função quando o usuário inserir algo na caixa de texto. Veja o código abaixo:

```js
function maxLen(input) {
  if (input.value.length > 10) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="searchInput" type="number" name="localizar" id="localizar" placeholder="numero do cliente" oninput="maxLen(this)">
```